# 'AnyObject' Doesn't have a Member "contactUID" Even thought Intelitype Says it Does?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, xcode, swift

Another ameture hour Swift Programming Question.

I have been returning values for an object from an array of object "Any Object" "Results". The intellitype says I have an object in the array with a value "ContactUID" however when I try to use ContactUID I get an error saying 'AnyObject' Doesn't contain member 'contactUID'.

The Array called HBCContactList successfully returns, FirstName, LastName and all the other items listed on the screen in the code. However it Will not return the Value 'ContactUID'.

The Model has got the right item. However unlike all the others... ContactUID is a INT64 instead of a string... I have added some screenshots to assit with the process of explaining. Sorry it sounds complicated but I expect I am missing something stupid.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete on iOS isn't always accurate, often it will just list all possible selectors / methods.

The root of your problem here is that even though you know HCCContactList holds only HBCDirectoryModel objects, the compiler doesn't as `MOContext.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)` returns an Array which declares it contains `AnyObject`'s (`[AnyObject]` / `Array<AnyObject>`). In order to refer to any of these objects as an `HBCDirectoryModel` you'll need to conduct a cast to this type.

The easiest way to do this is is to declare your `HCCContactList` as being an array of `HBCDirectoryModel`'s instead of `AnyObject`'s, and then casting the result of calling `MOContext.executeFetchRequest()` to this same type.

You can do this as follows

```
var HCCContactList: Array<HBCDirectoryModel> = []
HCCContactList = MOContext.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil) as Array<HBCDirectoryModel>
```

Or using the shorter syntax

```
var HCCContactList:[HBCDirectoryModel] = []
HCCContactList = MOContext.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil) as [HBCDirectoryModel]
```

Comment: Using your second shorter syntax has resolved the issue I was having. It does make a lot of sense what you are saying.. Would you say that declaring as ANYOBJECT is bad practice?

Comment: Yeah when working in Swift you should be specific about types, as it affords a lot of benefits. However as a lot of Apple framework's are written in Objective-C under the hood, often they'll return you `[AnyObject]` because Objective-C doesn't support generic collections. However as I showed above you can just convert them over to a generic collection with a quick 'as' cast.

Comment: Cheers Glen. I will switch a few of my others over as I want to be working on best practice as I continue to learn. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, happy Swifting